# How can I save the Xterm configuration I set at runtime?

Tags: configuration, xterm

I configured my xterm using the `CTRL-MiddleClick` and `CTRL-RightClick`. Is there a way to export save these settings?

Answer (score 8):

**Use editres**

You cannot save what you configured through XTerm's own menu. BUT, XTerm is a well behaved X application and as such it supports the *editres* protocol. So what you should do is:

1. Launch *XTerm*
2. Launch *editres*
3. Use the '*Get Tree*' command of *editres* to get the Xt widgets tree of the XTerm (you simply click on the XTerm)
4. Select the '*vt100*' widget and click on '*Show resource box*'
5. Look at the bottom of the resource box, you may have to resize it, and set the '*Save File*' filename
6. Click on the wanted resources and set their values
7. When done, click the '*Save file*' button and quit *editres*

The save file can now appended to your .Xdefaults.

**Example of what I got by this procedure:**

```
.xterm.vt100.utf8: true
.xterm.vt100.utf8Fonts: true
.xterm.vt100.utf8Title: true
.xterm.vt100.vt100Graphics: true
.xterm.vt100.dynamicColors: true
.xterm.vt100.reverseVideo: true
.xterm.vt100.rightScrollBar: true
.xterm.vt100.scrollBar: true
.xterm.vt100.colorRVMode: true
```

Beware, some options take effects only when some other option changes. For instance: *rightScrollBar* is looked up by Xterm only when *scrollBar* changed from false to true.

But all in all you should have the possibility to do the configuration you want.

**Links:**

- http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/editres.1.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can save settings of a running Xterm to a file. Xterm settings are specified via [X resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). Each of the entries in the menu corresponds to a resource. The [manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xterm.1.html#sect6) lists the available resources. Near the end of the resource section, you'll find a description of the menus, and for each menu entry, a description of the [action](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xterm.1.html#sect11) it invokes; and for each action, the manual indicates what it does, which can be to modify a setting controlled by a resource.

When your X session starts, resources are loaded from `~/.Xdefaults`. You can reload the file at any time by running

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```

For example, to enable the blinking cursor and allow applications to change the window title, put this in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
XTerm.VT100.allowTitleOps: true
XTerm.VT100.blink: true
```

Comment: There's no way to even dump or query the various XTerm resources? Not cool :(

Comment: @Shurane You can dump the resources with `xrdb -query`, but that shows the default settings applied when XTerm starts, not the current settings of an XTerm window.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use X11's `appres` utility. For your case, you want to query the the `XTerm` class, or more specifically the `VT100` class.

```
appres XTerm
```

Or

```
appres VT100
```

Both commands will output values in the same format as `.Xresources` uses.

Redirect/pipe to a file to save them.

```
appres VT100 | tee VT100resources.txt
```