# How can I find the default (font) resource XTerm is using?

Tags: x11, fonts, xterm, defaults, x-resources

If I launch `xterm` with its default bitmap fonts and then select the 'Large' font from the 'VT Fonts' menu (via `ctrl+right mouse`), I get a very usable bitmap font with apparently good Japanese character support.

**I'd like to know what this font is** so that I can use it elsewhere.  Unfortunately, I've found no information on what default settings XTerm uses (i.e. when none are explicitly specified).  Lots of sites show how to use X resources to specify new settings (e.g. particular fonts), but none I've seen say what defaults are used if I do nothing.

I've tried eyeballing the font, and it looks similar to and is the same width as `9x15`, but it uses more vertical space.  It appears not to be `9x15` with different line spacing, though, as specifying this font directly fails to display some Japanese characters that 'Large' can handle just fine.

Although I'll be happy to know what this specific font is, I really want to know where to find **what defaults XTerm uses for its resources** more generally.  If it makes any difference, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit.

[I have seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35748/5602) on the subject already, which is why I'm specifically asking about defaults rather than trying to get live values from a running XTerm.]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`appres`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/appres.1.xhtml) utility lists the resources used by an application, both user and default.

```
appres XTerm xterm
```

The first argument is the class name (`xterm -class Xxx`). The second argument, which is optional, is the instance name (`xterm -name xxx`).

The “Large” font is `.VT100.font5` or `.VT100.utf8Fonts.font5`. See the manual for whether `.utf8Fonts` is used, it's a bit complex. If you have more than one among `*.VT100.font5` and `?.VT100.font5` and `XTerm.VT100.font5` and `xterm.VT100.font5`, the last one in this list applies; see the [X documentation](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading14) for the gory details of resource name precedence.

```
appres XTerm | grep font5
```

Comment: When I do `appres XTerm` on my debian testing machine I only get `*customization: -color` :-/

Comment: @user640916 maybe like me you mistyped and wrote "Xterm xterm" instead of "XTerm xterm?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `lsof` to list all files by given process id and grep for fonts.

```
lsof  -p <process_id_of_xterm> | grep fonts
```

for example,

```
lsof -p `ps -a | grep xterm | cut -d' ' -f1` | grep fonts
```

sample output:

```
$ lsof -p `ps -a | grep xterm | cut -d' ' -f1` | grep fonts
xterm   17560 testuser  mem    REG  253,1    137272  9154732 /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
xterm   17560 testuser  mem    REG  253,1    139628  9154735 /usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Did not work for me, nothing at all output.

Comment: It would not help for bitmap-fonts, since those are on the server.

Answer (score 11):

- For fonts: `xterm -report-fonts`.
- For colours: `xterm -report-colors`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -- it queries the X server resource database

```
% xrdb -q| grep -i font
```

See also

```
% man xrdb
```

Answer (score 3):

Your can find the default font by running

```
$ fc-match mono
```

Here is the explanation (from the [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#TERM_Environmental_Variable))

> `xterm`'s default font is the bitmap font named by the X Logical Font
> Description alias fixed, often resolving to
>
> ```
> -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-?
> ```
>
> This font, also aliased to the name 6x13, has remakably wide coverage for unicode glyphs. The default "TrueType" font is the 14‑point font matched by the name mono. The FreeType font that will be used can be found with this command:
>
> ```
> $ fc-match mono
> ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that link-only answers are discouraged as they can become invalid when the link becomes dead or the page linked to changes. If possible, edit your post to add at least a summary of what the external page recommends to do to solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Thank you. That ok.

Comment: Thank you. I only took the liberty to apply a minor edit to your post to make it more readable.

Comment: Glad for that. It teaches me for the next time. Thanks!

Comment: All the misc unicode fonts... (ends in "-iso10646-1") have a very good set of glyphs, thanks the the hard work of the font maintainer Markus Kuhn back when unicode was still new.
HOWEVER:  bold bold fonts generally do not have all the glyphs.  these out out put dotted boxes insead!
EG try...   echo $'●\e[1m●\e[m'    to test normal and bold

Answer (score 1):

I had the *exact* same issue as OP. Trying appres gave me no input & editres didn't help for me either (the other stack overflow question).

anyway, I used xlsfonts with trial & error to just find the font from the big list of fonts. It wasn't one of the nice simple font names like 9x15 or anything.

```
xterm -fn -misc-fixed-bold-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso8859-9
```

on my system defaulted to the nice large size and printed unicode correctly. 
to prove a point,

```
xterm -fn -misc-fixed-bold-r-normal--0-0-75-75-c-0-iso8859-9
```

defaulted to a small
size that could not even print the unicode (oddly enough right clicking to large made it match the former).

for me, it wasn't very intuitive and it would have been nice to have someone reassure me as I struggled that 2 fonts in the list may look nearly identical but can still be rendered differently by xterm for some odd reason.

Comment: The xterm font selection code is very smart and will often automatically select normal bold, italic and bold italic fonts based on the font name you give.   Are you sure you actually got BOLD and your main font!

Comment: Also many of the bold 'misc' fonts do not have unicode glyphs, though the 'medium' or plain font, does.  Instead they output doted boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question while looking for something else. Since this question came up, I want to share that answer.

This answer comes from a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35748/how-can-i-save-the-xterm-configuration-i-set-at-runtime#comment78201_35756) by @Gilles_'SO-_stop_being_evil', actually a comment in response to their own [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35756/291375). If @Gilles wants to take credit for this answer and post it as their own, they are welcome to do so.

I quote the relevant information with emphasis (in bold) added:

> You can dump the resources with `xrdb -query`, but that shows the **default settings applied when XTerm starts**, **not the current settings** of an XTerm window.

When I ran `xrdb -query`, I got the same text as was in my `~/.Xresources` file, just in a different order. So, as @Gilles said, it's the default when you launch `xterm`, which may be fed in by `~/.Xresources` (or `~/.Xdefaults`, if that's what you use). I was thinking it would show what I would call "the factory defaults". I'm not sure if you're looking for the starting defaults or the factory defaults, but this information has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

[*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands) tells the developer how to obtain the font specification:

> ***`OSC`*** *Ps* ; *Pt* ***`ST`***
>
> Set Text Parameters.  Some control sequences return information:
>
> - For colors and font, if *Pt* is a "?", the control sequence elicits a response which consists of the control sequence
>   which would set the corresponding value.
> - The **`dtterm`** control sequences allow you to determine the icon name and window title.

and for [OSC 50](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-5-0.1019):

> *Ps* = ***`5 0`***  ⇒  Set Font to *Pt*.
>
> These controls may be disabled using the [**`allowFontOps`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:allowFontOps) resource.  If *Pt* begins with a "#", index in the font menu, relative (if the next character is a plus or minus sign) or absolute.  A number is expected but not required after the sign (the default is the current entry for relative, zero for absolute indexing).
>
> The same rule (plus or minus sign, optional number) is used when querying the font.  The remainder of *Pt* is ignored. A font can be specified after a "#" index expression, by adding a space and then the font specifier.
>
> If the *TrueType Fonts* menu entry is set (the [**`renderFont`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:renderFont)
> resource), then this control sets/queries the [**`faceName`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName)
> resource.

The [xtermcontrol](https://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/) program uses this feature (see the `--get-font` option).

Regarding the other answers:

- the [`--report-fonts`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-report-fonts) option would give useful data, though OP might find it **too** much data.  An answer using that option should illustrate it with sample output to show what to look for.
- `appres` only tells what resources are read from external files.  Besides compiled-in defaults, and the [`utf8fonts`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:utf8Fonts) and [`faceName`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName) resources preclude a simple answer using that route.
- by default xterm uses bitmap fonts, and does not actually open those files (the X server does that).  `lsof` can show which TrueType fonts xterm is using.